# Providing credential but cant connect to SSRS

Tags: sql-server, iis, reporting-services

It's been 2 days now can't configure the proper setting for SSRS. I am trying to relate the reportserver$sqlexpress to my server named (gateway-PC). I installed IIS first, later while configuring the WEB SERVICE URL, I provided the same domain with port 80, all went good but when I open the url in browser, windows security message prompt and ask me for my credentials after proving them 3 times the page remain blank... what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your browser with Administrator Privileges